# Disable automatic validation of input object in ApiPlatform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have configured ApiPlatform for CQRS using Symfony messenger, as described here: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/messenger/#using-messenger-with-an-input-object . My entity looks similar to:

```php
#[
    ORM\Entity(),
    ORM\Table(name: '`presents`'),
    ApiResource(
        collectionOperations: [
            'get',
            'post' => [
                'messenger' => 'input',
                'input' => AddPresentRequest::class,
            ],
        ],
        itemOperations: ['get'],
    ),
]
class Present
{
    // ...
```

I've then added some symfony constraints to the DTO object:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

final class AddPresentRequest
{
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(
        max: 180
    )]
    private string $name;

    // ...
```

Now ApiPlatform automatically validates the request entity before passing it to the message bus.

I want it to **not** do that.

The reason is that while validation works great for API requests, it works *only* for API requests. I want the validation to also run when doing this:

```php
/** @var MessageBusInterface $messageBus */
$messageBus->dispatch(new AddPresentRequest($name));  // api-platform doesn't trigger validation
```

Adding validation to the message bus is easy, all I need is to enable `ValidationMiddleware` as described [in this symfony-docs issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/10474#issuecomment-640267192). With that, the messenger always triggers the validation.

However, this means that for API requests, the validator runs twice—once triggered by ApiPlatform, and then again by ValidationMiddleware. This is why I need to tell ApiPlatform to chill and that I got this.

I could not find anything in ApiPlatform docs about how to disable automatic validation. The docs [mention](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/validation) that I can replace the validator with something custom, which I thought might give a clue, but unfortunately there is no actual information about how to go about replacing it.

One workaround that I have found is that I can set a bogus validation groups on the entity: `validationGroups: ['non-existent']`. This is imperfect though, because while the constraints are not checked, the validator still runs and parses the entity twice.

How can I disable ApiPlatform's automatic validation, so that I can handle the validation elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable [the built in validation event listener](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#built-in-event-listeners) in your operation configuration:

```php
#[
    ApiResource(
        collectionOperations: [
            'post' => [
                'messenger' => 'input',
                'input' => AddPresentRequest::class,
                'validate' => false, //disables the validation event listener
            ],
        ],
    ),
]
```

This should prevent API Platform from (automatically) validating your input DTO.

Comment: Any way this can be done as a global setting?